# Matrix multiplication using three different methods gives different results, depending on amount of values

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, armadillo

I would like to multiply two matrices `A` and `B`, and wanted to compare three different methods. One of them is simply iterating over the columns of `B` and multiplying them by the matrix `A`, the second one is using the function `each_col()` from armadillo, and applying a lambda, and the third one is simply the multiplication `A * B`. The resulting code is shown below:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>

#include <armadillo>

constexpr int num_values = 2048;
constexpr int num_rows = 128;
constexpr int num_cols = num_values / num_rows;

constexpr int bench_rounds = 100;

void test_multiply_loop(const arma::mat &in_mat,
                        const arma::mat &init_mat,
                        arma::mat &out_mat) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_mat.n_cols; ++i) {
        out_mat.col(i) = init_mat * in_mat.col(i);
    }
}

void test_multiply_matrix(const arma::mat &in_mat,
                          const arma::mat &init_mat,
                          arma::mat &out_mat) {
    out_mat = init_mat * in_mat;
}

void test_multiply_lambda(const arma::mat &in_mat,
                          const arma::mat &init_mat,
                          arma::mat &out_mat) {
    out_mat = in_mat;
    out_mat.each_col([init_mat](arma::colvec &a) {
        a = init_mat * a;
    });
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << "\n";
    //Create matrix
    arma::colvec test_vec = arma::linspace(1, num_values, num_values);
    arma::mat init_mat = arma::reshape(test_vec, num_rows, num_cols);
    arma::mat out_mat_loop = arma::zeros(num_rows, num_cols),
            out_mat_lambda = arma::zeros(num_rows, num_cols),
            out_mat_matrix = arma::zeros(num_rows, num_cols);
    arma::mat test_mat = arma::eye(num_rows, num_rows);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i)
        for(size_t j = 0; j < num_rows; ++j)
            test_mat(i, j) *= (i + 1);

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < bench_rounds; ++i)
        test_multiply_loop(init_mat, test_mat, out_mat_loop);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < bench_rounds; ++i)
        test_multiply_lambda(init_mat, test_mat, out_mat_lambda);
    auto t4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto t5 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < bench_rounds; ++i)
        test_multiply_matrix(init_mat, test_mat, out_mat_matrix);
    auto t6 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Multiplication by loop:\t\t" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Multiplication by lambda:\t" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t4 - t3 ).count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Multiplication by internal:\t" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t6 - t5 ).count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Loop and matrix are equal:\t" << arma::approx_equal(out_mat_loop, out_mat_matrix, "reldiff", 0.1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Loop and lambda are equal:\t" << arma::approx_equal(out_mat_loop, out_mat_lambda, "reldiff", 0.1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Matrix and lambda are equal:\t" << arma::approx_equal(out_mat_matrix, out_mat_lambda, "reldiff", 0.1) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Now, for `num_rows = 128` my output is

```
Multiplication by loop:         124525
Multiplication by lambda:       46690
Multiplication by internal:     1270
Loop and matrix are equal:      0
Loop and lambda are equal:      0
Matrix and lambda are equal:    0
```

but for `num_rows = 64` my output is

```
Multiplication by loop:         32305
Multiplication by lambda:       6517
Multiplication by internal:     56344
Loop and matrix are equal:      1
Loop and lambda are equal:      1
Matrix and lambda are equal:    1
```

Why is the output so different when increasing the amount of columns? And why is the timing of the functions changing so much?

Comment: @idclev463035818: I just rechecked, but I still can't see my mistake?

Comment: The code is correct. It is just confusing because you changed the other of the matrix multiplication compared to the order of the function parameters. But this is consistent in the three functions and thus they should return the same output.

Comment: @darcamo: That's exactly the problem, for a change of the matrix size I do not get the same results if `num_rows` is above a certain value. I also do not understand why the timing is varying so much

Comment: sorry my bad, misread the code

Comment: The timing will be always better (or the same) if you do just `A * B` because armadillo (some blas implementation) can perform the multiplication in some "smart way". Many  people have worked over decades to optimize this operation (including using some specific functionaly of the CPU - check the mkl library as an example). If you do a loop it will work, but it might prevent the optimized code from being used. This is also the reason why `for_each` **might** be better than the raw loop.

Answer (score 1):

The three functions are indeed doing the same thing and the result should be the same, except for precision differences which should not matter since you compare the results with `arma::approx_equal`.

In my machine the output was correct for both sizes you mention and for other higher values that I have tried. I could not reproduce the problem.

For reference, I'm tried with armadillo 9.870.2 and I linked with openblas and lapack.

**How did you install armadillo?**

Armadillo uses blas and lapack for much of its functionality. For matrix multiplication it's using some blas implementation. There are several implementations for blas, such as openblas, mkl even cublas (for runing in the gpu), etc..

Armadillo can work without a blas implementation, where it would use its own (slower) implementation for matrix multiplication. I haven't tried it using its own implementation without linking with blas.

Another point that might be related is that depending on the blas implementation the matrix multiplication might use multiple threads, but usually only for large matrices, since using multiple threads for small matrices would hurt performance. That is, the code path used to perform the multiplication could be different depending on the matrix size (but of course it would be a bug if both code paths do not produce the same answer).